# Using FLV player with local html without webserver

Tags: javascript, html, flv

I'm trying to embed a player in my html file to show a video in a browser. I use the player_flv_js.swf as you can see in [Preview](http://flv-player.net/players/js/preview.)

My problem is that when I use a apache (like in xampp) there's no problem but having it only in a html file I get the error 'Error calling method on NPObject!' Because it is working within a webserver and not with local files I think it is a question of configuration or that for a local file the falsh player (and its objects) are not available.

Is there a way to embed the swf in a html file and display it without using a webserver and get the embedded swf running?

Any tipp could help. Thanks in advance!

parascus

Comment: HTML5 `<video>` works without a web server. Just sayin'

Comment: Hi Šime Vidas, that's a possibility. It seems that for this I have to convert the videos to ogg and mp4 which is not a big problem. But how can I get a javascript function called after the video is finished when I use the video tag? Do you have a link with a documentation of this feature (if there is)?

Comment: Hi again, ok, I found the html5 documentation of w3schools. There I should find my answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read Mozilla's MDN documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Thanks again Šime Vidas, this helps.